# deserialize json with different propertyValue types

Tags: c#

I want to deserialize (and afterwards serialize again) the following Json

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "custom_fields": [
      {
        "definition": "field1",
        "value": "stringvalue"
      },      
      {
        "definition": "field2",
        "value": [ "arrayvalue1", "arrayvalue2" ]
      },
      {
        "definition": "field3",
        "value": {
          "type": "user",
          "id": "1245"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

The type of the value if different (field1: string, field2: array, field3: an extra nested structure).
This what I have:

```
public class CustomField
{
    public string Definition { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<CustomField> Custom_fields { get; set; }
}
```

The Value-field is defined as object, but this is a problem when serializing again, especially the nested structure for field3.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a custom converter for your `Value` property:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = 
                @"{
                  ""id"": ""12345"",
                  ""custom_fields"": [
                      {
                        ""definition"": ""field1"",
                        ""value"": ""stringvalue""
                      }, {
                        ""definition"": ""field2"",
                        ""value"": [ ""arrayvalue1"", ""arrayvalue2"" ]
                      }, {
                        ""definition"": ""field3"",
                        ""value"": {
                          ""type"": ""user"",
                          ""id"": ""1245""
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                }";

            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject));
        }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "custom_fields")]
        public List<CustomField> CustomFields { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomField
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "definition")]
        public string Definition { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomValueConverter))]
        public dynamic Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomValueConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        // By returning false, we let the default `WriteJson` kick in
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            } 

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize<string[]>(reader);
            }

            return serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(reader);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```